# Sqlite Constraint failed on update

Tags: sqlite

The following query somehow gives a Constraint failed error:

```
UPDATE dimensionitems 
SET    vitemcode = itemcode 
                   || '_' 
                   || Substr('0000' 
                             || (SELECT (SELECT Count(1) 
                                         FROM   dimensionitems t2 
                                         WHERE  t2.itemcode = t1.itemcode 
                                                AND t2.rowid <= t1.rowid) AS no 
                                 FROM   dimensionitems t1 
                                 WHERE  t1.rowid = dimensionitems.rowid 
                                 ORDER  BY t1.itemcode, 
                                           t1.dimvalue1, 
                                           t1.dimvalue2), -4, 4)
```

the error: `UNIQUE constraint failed: dimensionitems.vitemcode, dimensionitems.dimvalue1, dimensionitems.dimvalue2: UPDATE dimensionitems ...`

## test 1

But when i do a group by over the query result and check duplicates on the column values, i get none:

```
SELECT Count(*), 
       v2 
FROM   (SELECT itemcode, 
               dimvalue1, 
               dimvalue2, 
               itemcode 
               || '_' 
               || Substr('0000' 
                         || (SELECT (SELECT Count(1) 
                                     FROM   dimensionitems t2 
                                     WHERE  t2.itemcode = t1.itemcode 
                                            AND t2.rowid <= t1.rowid) AS no 
                             FROM   dimensionitems t1 
                             WHERE  t1.rowid = dimensionitems.rowid 
                             ORDER  BY t1.itemcode, 
                                       t1.dimvalue1, 
                                       t1.dimvalue2), -4, 4) AS v2 
        FROM   dimensionitems) r 
GROUP  BY dimvalue1, 
          dimvalue2, 
          v2 
HAVING Count(*) > 1
```

gives no result, which means no duplicates right?

`0 Rows returned from: select COUNT(*)`

## Test 2

I checked if anything updates at all with the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT itemcode, 
               dimvalue1, 
               dimvalue2, 
               vitemcode, 
               itemcode 
               || '_' 
               || Substr('0000' 
                         || (SELECT (SELECT Count(1) 
                                     FROM   dimensionitems t2 
                                     WHERE  t2.itemcode = t1.itemcode 
                                            AND t2.rowid <= t1.rowid) AS no 
                             FROM   dimensionitems t1 
                             WHERE  t1.rowid = dimensionitems.rowid 
                             ORDER  BY t1.itemcode, 
                                       t1.dimvalue1, 
                                       t1.dimvalue2), -4, 4) AS v2 
        FROM   dimensionitems) r 
WHERE  vitemcode != v2
```

but this also yielded no results.

Can it be Sqllite update rows one by one and checks integraty one by one?
And it blocks on updating it's own rows wit the same value?

### Notes

- This constraint is not the primary key.
- there is also a unique constraint on Vitemcode itself to be always unique
- Also it seems like nothing would actualy update since the vitemcode would stay the same

## My Final results:

The table had two constraints

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IX_DI_VirtualItemCode] ON [dimensionitems] (    [vitemcode] ASC)​
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IX_DI_VirtualItemCode_dimvalue1_dimvalue2] ON [dimensionitems] (    [vitemcode] ASC,    [dimvalue1] ASC,    [dimvalue2] ASC)
```

By this i concluded: If vitemcode is unqiue (which has te be because of constraint 1), the Combination of vitemcode, dimvalue1, and dimvalue2 will also always be unique.

With this reason i removed the second constraint, and it all started working again​

Answer (score 1):

Yes, SQLite checks constraints when each row is updated.

You could update the rows with some unique prefix or suffix to prevent duplicates, and then remove it later:

```
UPDATE dimensionitems SET vitemcode = 'blah' || ...;
UPDATE dimensionitems SET vitemcode = substr(vitemcode, 5);
```

Comment: Does it also mean if i set vitemcode with the same value the constraint error hits?

Comment: No, a row cannot conflict with itself.